# Image quality in figure environment on two columns

Tags: floats, two-column

I am trying to understand why my figure quality is so bad in the "figure" environment, on a two columns document. It is barely unreadable, even with a zoom of 200%. Most of articles I am reading are able to have a good quality, even on a two column environment. My pictures are coming from excel graphics. I am importing these graphics on visio and then save the JPEG. The resulting picture is actually quite correct, in normal size.

Here is my LaTeX code to align multiple figure (2 per line):

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Pictures/Results/KKT_CPLEX_MAXP/no_classes/messages_comparison}
        \caption{Number of exchanges, no classes}
        \label{fig:msg1}
    \endminipage
    \hfill
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Pictures/Results/KKT_CPLEX_MAXP/ksharp_socinc_chrconhour/messages_comparison}
        \caption{Number of messages exchanged, ARR\_k\_sharp + SOC\_inc\_demand + CHR\_con\_hour}
        \label{fig:msg2}
    \endminipage
    \hfill
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Pictures/Results/KKT_CPLEX_MAXP/sharp_socinc_chrchgcdur/messages_comparison}
        \caption{Number of messages exchanged, ARR\_sharp + SOC\_inc\_demand + CHR\_chg\_duration}
        \label{fig:msg3}
    \endminipage
    \hfill
    \centering
    \minipage{0.22\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Pictures/Results/KKT_CPLEX_MAXP/smooth_socdec_chrincdur/messages_comparison}
        \caption{Number of messages, ARR\_smooth + SOC\_dec\_duration + CHR\_inc\_duration}
        \label{fig:msg4}
    \endminipage
\end{figure}
```

I am getting the following result (200% zoom, it should be readable at 100%) :
[image]

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Probably JPEG it's the problem. Try to save them as PDF or in vectorial graph, everything would be more clear. Also I think TeX has some problems dealing with JPEG.

Comment: If you scale a bitmap such as jpg then the result depends a lot on the resolution of the original image, but the results, especially with text are always going to be variable. Also separately you probbaly want to change your settings for `\caption` so that it is `\raggedright` rather than justified.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I am not dealing with the captions yet, I am also having some problem with the package to lower their font, doesn't seem to work very well. I will try and come back here to keep you guys in touch.

Comment: I have tried PNG, PDF and Scalable Vector Graphics, results look the same. I will try to improve the quality of the source picture.

Comment: Are you exactly talking about the image quality, when you state it is unreadable, i.e. the text is pixelated? If so, this problem can impossibly occur in pdf (since it is vector based) unless your visio program (which I do not know) converts the image in bitmap and then only encapsulates it in pdf. Why do you not print the graphs directly in pdf from Excel, any resoanably up-to-date version can do this. Or do you mean the graphics are unlegible because of the font size? In this case you just have to change your original plot, easy enough in Excel.

Comment: BTW, you might want to use \raggedright or \sloppy in your captions.  The caption package can set that up for you.  Also, what happens when you zoom in?